# R: How to take the min and max or other functions of every n rows

Tags: r, dataframe, max, min

I have a dataframe of which I put one variable into a vector.

From this vector, I would like to calculate for every 5 values `mean`, `min` and `max` value.

I have managed to calculate the means in this way:

```
means <- colMeans(matrix(df$values, nrow=5))
```

I know I can calculate the min and max like this:

```
max <- max(df$values[1:5])
min <- min(df$values[1:5])
```

How do I repeat this for *every* five values?

### Edit:

Aditionally, how can I get statistic and p-value from a 1-sample t-test for each n-row?

Comment: What is your aim really? Do you need to `roll` your data with a specific function? I mean do you need to compute for example the mean of `1:5,2:6,3:7,4:8` etc or do you just need the mean of `1:5,6:10,11:15`etc?All these take into consideration 5 rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sapply` and `split` for this:

```
sapply(split(df$value, rep(1:(nrow(df)/5), each=5)), mean)
sapply(split(df$value, rep(1:(nrow(df)/5), each=5)), min)
sapply(split(df$value, rep(1:(nrow(df)/5), each=5)), max)
```

If you want the outputs in a matrix you can use what [@lmo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45714557/r-how-to-take-the-min-and-max-of-every-n-rows/45714669?noredirect=1#comment78387940_45714669) proposed in the comments:

```
sapply(split(df$value, rep(1:(nrow(df)/5), each=5)),
                       function(x) c(mean=mean(x), min=min(x), max=max(x)))
```

## Update

***How to get statistic and p-value from a sample t-test for each n-row:*** This would be a bit harder to implement. Look below;

```
#mu=3 for sample t-test
t_test_list <- sapply(split(df$value, rep(1:(nrow(df)/5), each=5)), t.test, mu=3) 

p_value_list <- lapply(as.data.frame(t_test_list),function(x) x$p.value)
statistic_list <- lapply(as.data.frame(t_test_list),function(x) x$statistic)
```

`p_value_list` and `statistic_list` are `p.value` and `statistic` for each 5 rows.

Comment: And these can be combined into a single line if desired: `sapply(split(1:15, rep(1:3, each=5)), function(x) c(mean=mean(x), min=min(x), max=max(x)))` for example. or for min/max alone, may as well use `range`: `sapply(split(1:15, rep(1:5, each=5, length.out=15)), range)`.

Comment: @lmo You're right. I am not sure in what structure OP wants them. If he wants to put them all in a matrix your solution works.

Comment: Also `tapply` and `by` are pretty natural tools here, though `tapply` uses `ans <- lapply(X = split(X, group), FUN = FUN, ...)` under the hood.

Comment: Would there then also be a way to do a 1 sample t-test over every 5 values, putting the statistic and p-value in new variables?

Answer (score 3):

**1) tapply** Below `g`  is a grouping variable consisting of fives ones, fives twos and so on.  `range` provides the minimum and maximum resulting in a list output from `tapply` and then `simplify2array` reduces that to an array.  Omit the `simlify2array` if you want a list output.  `out[1, ]` would be the minima and `out[2, ]` would be the maxima.

```
values <- 1:100 # test input

n <- length(values)
g <- rep(1:n, each = 5, length = n)
out <- simplify2array(tapply(values, g, range))
```

giving:

```
> out
     1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19  20
[1,] 1  6 11 16 21 26 31 36 41 46 51 56 61 66 71 76 81 86 91  96
[2,] 5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 50 55 60 65 70 75 80 85 90 95 100
```

**2) aggregate**  This would also work:

```
ag <- aggregate(values, list(g = g), range)
```

giving this data.frame where the first column is `g` and the second column is the transpose of the matrix in (1).  Here `ag[[2]][, 1]` is the minima and `ag[[2]][, 2]` is the maxima.  If you want to flatten `ag` try `do.call(data.frame, ag)` or `do.call(cbind, ag)` depending on whether you want a 3 column data frame or matrix.

```
> ag
    g x.1 x.2
1   1   1   5
2   2   6  10
3   3  11  15
4   4  16  20
5   5  21  25
6   6  26  30
7   7  31  35
8   8  36  40
9   9  41  45
10 10  46  50
11 11  51  55
12 12  56  60
13 13  61  65
14 14  66  70
15 15  71  75
16 16  76  80
17 17  81  85
18 18  86  90
19 19  91  95
20 20  96 100
```

Answer (score 1):

Certainly an atypical way to do it, and maybe not the most efficient, but you could try `zoo::rollapply`. This gives you more info than you need, but you can then filter down to only what you want:

```
vals <- 1:20
zoo::rollapply(vals, 5, function(x) c(min = min(x), max = max(x), mean = mean(x)))[seq(from = 1, to = length(vals), by = 5),]

    min max mean
[1,]   1   5    3
[2,]   6  10    8
[3,]  11  15   13
[4,]  16  20   18
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who love `dplyr` and want to preserve the structure of the data, you can use the `RcppRoll` package

```
 df <- data.frame(
   Time = 1:10,
   Value = sample(100:200, 10)
 )

> df
   Time Value
#1     1   122
#2     2   185
#3     3   138
#4     4   134
#5     5   167
#6     6   197
#7     7   161
#8     8   171
#9     9   152
#10   10   106
```

Now finding the max

```
df%>%mutate(
   ad = RcppRoll::roll_maxr(Value, 3, fill = "0")
 )
   Time Value  ad
#1     1   122   0
#2     2   185   0
#3     3   138 185
#4     4   134 185
#5     5   167 167
#6     6   197 197
#7     7   161 197
#8     8   171 197
#9     9   152 171
#10   10   106 171
```